# extract substring dynamically using python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string: **AA12345678SDA_ABC-ABCD_INRA-202311042055-202311052055.zip** from which I am extracting multiple values using the following regex:

```
    r'(?P<name>[A-Z0-9]+(?P<id>\d{4}))(?P<type>[A-Z]{3})?' + \
    r'_ABC-ABCD_INRA-(?P<ts_range>\d{12}-\d{12})\.zip')
```

While extracting the **type**, it works only when it is 3 characters because it is hardcoded. Is there a way to get it dynamically, irrespective of character length i.e., anything before **_ABC-ABCD_INRA-** and name(AA12345678)
Example: AA12345678SD_ABC-ABCD_INRA-202311042055-202311052055.zip

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `{1,}` instead of `{3}` which you are using as the exact 3 `[A-Z]` length. Here, `{1,}` suggests at least 1 among `[A-Z]` character. This can also be replaced with a `+`. Also, if you want to capture 0 or more [A-Z] characters you can also use `*`.

```
(?P<name>[A-Z0-9]+(?P<id>\d{4}))(?P<type>[A-Z]{1,})(?=_ABC-ABCD_INRA-(?P<ts_range>\d{12}-\d{12})\.zip)
                                               ^^ Here
```

***[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wHAvWp/1)***

**EDIT:**

You just need to replace `{1,}` with `+` or `*`.

- `+` - it is a special character which means at least one. So in your case it means any uppercase character(A-Z) which can come 1 or more time.

```
(?P<name>[A-Z0-9]+(?P<id>\d{4}))(?P<type>[A-Z]+)(?=_ABC-ABCD_INRA-(?P<ts_range>\d{12}-\d{12})\.zip)
                                              ^^ Here
```

- `*` - it is a special character which means **0 or more**. So in your case it means any uppercase character(A-Z) which can come 0 or more time. In this case,

Comment: Thanks a lot! that works. Could you help me with an example using * and + ?

Comment: @KingstonX I have updated my answer. Please have a look and let me know if you need more explanation.